# How to connect a chessboard and a cipher into puzzle?

Tags: cipher, puzzle-creation, checkerboard

Let's say you have (a) a chessboard with figures and (b) a text from a book. The figures configuration is the Cardan grille, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardan_grille

When you put the chessboard on the text, you need to read the word from the letters that are under the figures.

Question. How to connect the chessboard and the text into a puzzle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you meant something like this, example puzzle:

```
The King's Gambit:
Chess opening that begins to be popular again:    
1. e4 e5    
2. f4 (White is weirdly offering a pawn)
Now when you know how message works,
you can try it yourself.
Or I should be describing hide and seek?
Sorry for format, hope it is enough.
```

And solution for this is obvious:

> Just play The King's Gambit
>  [image: chess]
>  Secret message is same as playing it - e2->e4->e7->e5->f2->f4
>  = Describing how to weirdly hide message

Or you can try some "unique check in 3 moves" or something like that, but if you try to literally "put it on text" - you would have to be good at it, since changing one letter could affect everything else. Also there will be more words in one square (or less letters if text is too big). With some random text - I would say that is nearly impossible.

Comment: Thank for the idea, i think that i can use the playing order as the letters sequence for reading the secret text.

Comment: To make it easier to fill out the rest of the chessboard you can encrypt the text first (for puzzles some monoalphabetic substitution might be fun). That way you can fill out the rest of the chessboard with random characters without it being instantly obvious what text was added.